# Connecting to remote console on Dell iDRAC on R815 fails

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac, ubuntu-20.04

The iDRAC's virtual console uses `jnlp`.

I have installed:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-netx
```

Connecting to the iDRAC's webserver works using Firefox. When I click 'Launch Virtual Console' it starts the java app. The JVM then asks for a few permissions which I grant (the certificate is selfsigned). But it then fails with: "Connection failed".

I had this working when running Ubuntu 18.04, but it broke after upgrading the client to Ubuntu 20.04.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iDRAC uses RC4 which is now considered insecure.

It is disabled in:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/conf/security/java.security
```

Remove RC4 from:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
    EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
```

And then it works.